# Why loop is run till number becomes zero

Tags: c

Can somebody tell why keeps the loop till n becomes zero ..logic behind this code.

```
# include <stdio.h> 
# define  bool int 

/* Function to get parity of number n. It returns 1 
   if n has odd parity, and returns 0 if n has even 
   parity */
bool getParity(unsigned int n) 
{ 
    bool parity = 0; 
    while (n) 
    { 
        parity = !parity; 
        n      = n & (n - 1); 
    }         
    return parity; 
} 

/* Driver program to test getParity() */
int main() 
{ 
    unsigned int n = 7; 
    printf("Parity of no %d = %s",  n,  
             (getParity(n)? "odd": "even")); 

    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

code from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-parity/)

Comment: The site has explanation too.

Comment: Do you know what parity is?! the number of bits set modulo 2, possibly inverted. If there are only *zeroed bits* left there is nothing to count...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick rely on this binary operation:

`n = n & (n - 1);`

According to your website, it will unset (`1 -> 0`) the rightmost active bit from the previous value of `n`. The loop will continue until all active bits are unset.

For instance, if your number `n` contains 6 active bits (`n = 159 -> 10011111`), it will take 6 loop to unset all of them.

Start: `10011111`

1. `10011110`
2. `10011100`
3. `10011000`
4. `10010000`
5. `10000000`
6. `00000000`

As far as I'm aware, the value of an integer number without any active bits (`00000000`) is always equal to `0`. Thus the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the Boolean value of all integers except zero is True. And since, while statement test for exactly that the loop runs until value of `n` is zero. Once `n` is zero, the loop is not entered at all.

If your question is why the `n` decreases up to zero.
Bitwise `and` (`&`) between two unsigned integer always creates value less than or equal to lowest of two. This lower number is then assigned to `n` itself, so, `n` is decreasing in up to zero.

Some examples

`1111 & 0111 = 0111`

`0101 & 1010 = 0000`

`0100 & 0101 = 0100`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if evaluating parity using that loop is a requirement (but, pratically speaking that's not the best way to evaluate parity).

A number is odd if its final bit is 1, it's even otherwise. For this reason there's no reason to loop. You can simply:

```
bool getParity(unsigned int n) 
{ 
  return (bool)(n%2); 
}
```

Or, alternatively

```
bool getParity(unsigned int n) 
{ 
  return (bool)(n & 0x00000001 ); 
}
```